# How can I enforce ternary parentheses with RuboCop?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have a coding standard that suggests that the initial argument to a ternary should always be inside parenthesis, regardless of the expression.

E.g. `foo = (thing.baz?) ? [] : thing.bar`

The following should be considered an infraction:

E.g. `foo = thing.baz? ? [] : thing.bar`

Is it possible to achieve this with Rubocop's built-in Cops, or does this require a custom Cop. If so, how would I implement it?

Comment: AFIAK, there is no such a cop out of the box. In [rubocop tests](https://github.com/nevir/rubocop-rspec/tree/master/lib/rubocop/cop/rspec) there are examples and brief docs on how to create custom cops.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I saw your question, so I went ahead and implemented the cop for you. The name is `Style/TernaryParentheses`, and the `EnforcedStyle` option you want is `require_parentheses` (not the default.)

```
# .rubocop.yml
Style/TernaryParentheses:
  Enabled: true
  EnforcedStyle: require_parentheses
```

You can start using it right now, by putting this in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'rubocop', git: 'git://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop.git'
```

or you can wait for the `0.42.0` release.

Comment: That's awesome. Thank-you so very much!

Comment: No worries. Don't hesitate to file bug reports or feature requests in the GitHub repo. It is all very helpful. :-)